# Display Categories and Subcategories in Dropdown Menu

Tags: php, mysqli

Am trying to display categories and subcategories in a dropdown menu and I have this:

```
<?php


              $cat_query = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
              $select_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $cat_query);
              while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_array($select_categories)) {

                $cat_id = $cat['cat_id'];
                $cat_title = $cat['cat_title'];

                 echo "<li>";
                 echo "<a href='#'>$cat_title <span class='caret'></span></a>";

                 $sub_query = "SELECT * FROM `sub_categories` WHERE `cat_id` = $cat_id";
                 $select_sub_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $sub_query);

                 while ($sub = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sub_categories)) {

                  $subcat_id = $sub['subcat_id'];
                  $subcat_title = $sub['subcat_title'];
                  echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'><li>";
                  echo "<a href='#'>$subcat_title</a></li>";
                  echo "</ul>";
                }

                  echo "</li>";

               }

          ?>
```

It is actually fetching the categories from the database but it's not displaying correctly.

On the desktop version it displays like this:
[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV2VM.jpg)

On the mobile version it displays like this:
[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiyJJ.jpg)

Am I doing anything wrong?
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You want to display in a `dropdown menu` yet you are using `ul` and `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide the css,javascript or some html code , I assume the problem is in this php block

```
while ($sub = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sub_categories)) {

              $subcat_id = $sub['subcat_id'];
              $subcat_title = $sub['subcat_title'];
              echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'><li>";
              echo "<a href='#'>$subcat_title</a></li>";
              echo "</ul>";
            }
```

From this code block it seems like you are creating a list of drop down menu , so maybe it should be

```
echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
while ($sub = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sub_categories)) {

              $subcat_id = $sub['subcat_id'];
              $subcat_title = $sub['subcat_title'];
              echo "<li><a href='#'>$subcat_title</a></li>";
 }
echo "</ul>";
```

If this does not work You should check your javascript,css,html code again. Because I don't know your design plan

Comment: Where did you see the article that `mysqli_fetch_array()` is already deprecated?

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong word , but few years ago I found some article that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Irvin Thanks for pointing out my mistake , a quick research show that I'm wrong about that.

Comment: And those articles could be primarily `opinion-based` so stop telling it to others like it is a `MUST` especially to beginners unless you have strong proof about what you are talking. You didn't even posted the link to support your claim.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years, Thanks for the answer, it worked perfectly well!